# How to read NFC tags with ACR122U?

Tags: nfc, apdu

I have a ACR122U NFC reader. I have found an [example](http://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.nl/2010/04/pcsc-sample-in-c.html) how to access this with pcsc-lite (under Ubuntu). I can access the reader, but I have no luck reading any information from a tag. When I read information from the tag I get no response. I think it has to do with the command I send in the SCardTransmit call. But I have no idea what kind of APDU command I have to send to the tag to get a correct response.

Anybody done this before?

Comment: What type of tags do you have? You might need to wrap the command in a 'pseudo APDU' to actually send it to the tag, as described in the [manual](http://www.acs.com.hk/drivers/eng/API-ACR122U-2.02.pdf).

Comment: I have a tag with NTAG203 chip.

Comment: Are you sending ISO14443-3 commands ? Do you know the tag's protocol (NFC Forum type 1, 2, 4 ?).

Comment: You need to properly initialize the tag - it is in the docs. You can also try my https://github.com/skjolber/android-acr-nfc-reader-service-api if your requirements are simple